# how to convert Active Directory crt certificate to pem using Java instead of OpenSSL?

Tags: java, openssl, certificate, pem

How to convert an Active Directory crt certificate to a pem format using only Java instead of OpenSSL? i.e. accomplish the same as the following OpenSSL command:

```
openssl x509 -in C:\RSA9\certnew.cer -out C:\RSA9\certnew.pem -outform PEM
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you having trouble? As it stands, it looks like you are having trouble with commands - you don't know how to use Java's command line [`keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html).